# Is my ObjectCache wrapper sound?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cache, asp.net-mvc

Wrapper:

```
internal static class Cache
{
    private static ObjectCache InternalCache
    {
        get
        {
            return MemoryCache.Default;
        }
    }

    private static T CacheOrGetExisting<T>(string key, Func<T> valueFactory)
    {
        T value;
        object uncastedValue = InternalCache.Get(key);

        if (uncastedValue == null)
        {
            value = valueFactory();
            InternalCache.Set(key, value, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1));
        }
        else
        {
            value = (T)uncastedValue;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static decimal Foo
    {
        get
        {
            return CacheOrGetExisting("foo", () =>
                {
                    return 5m; // data access here
                });
        }
    }

    public static Bar Bar
    {
        get
        {
            return CacheOrGetExisting("bar", () =>
                {
                    return new Bar(); // data access here
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in a Controller:

```
model.Foo = Cache.Foo;
```

One thing I'm not sure of: is the readonly property necessary for `InternalCache` or can I write `private static ObjectCache InternalCache = MemoryCache.Default;`?

I'm not worried about the tiny chance of multiple calls to the same uncached object causing multiple `value = valueFactory();` and I'm also not worried about stale data. The main goal is to cache some informational data that is simply displayed on the screen, instead of retrieving it every request.

I've tested this with an expiration of 1 minute and a class that gets `DateTime.Now` on creation, and it worked fine, so I believe the code is bug-free.

Comment: I'd start getting worried long before I had this many `static`s in such a small area.

Comment: @Magus what would I gain from making `Cache` non-static? There's no state to be held here, just reads and writes to `MemoryCache.Default` (which is `static` because that's how you do in-memory caching in a web context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Magus pointed out in the comments, making everything static can present some issues. Using these static properties in other classes makes those classes tightly coupled to the `Cache` class. Why should you care? Consider this class:

```
public class Bar
{
    public int DoSomething()
    {
        return 5 + Cache.CachedNumber;
    }
}
```

You've lost your ability to test `DoSomething()` in isolation from the rest of your code. Any time you test `DoSomething()`, it relies on a specific implementation of `Cache`. It also makes it difficult to use the `Bar` class with different cache types (in memory, database, file system, etc.). Ideally, `Bar` would look something like this:

```
public class Bar
{
    private ICacheProvider Cache { get; set; }

    public Bar(ICacheProvider cache)
    {
        this.Cache = cache;
    }

    public int DoSomething()
    {
        return 5 + Cache.CachedNumber;
    }
}
```

Now we can:

1. Test that DoSomething is doing its job, regardless of flaws in the `ICacheProvider` instance (by passing a mock ICacheProvider that always returns `CachedNumber = 3`, for example).
2. Pass in different `ICacheProvider` implementations that can very depending on my use case, and `Bar` will still work without caring about them.

Also, I would suggest not using something as vague as `Cache` or `ICacheProvider` (used for illustration). Once you start caching a lot of things, you may want to cache different properties differently, at which point your super cache class will become too large to maintain. Consider breaking it up into meaningful repositories that can implement caching however they want, or something similar.